# Garamond Expert with Math Design not working

Tags: fonts, installing, math-fonts, mathdesign, installing-fonts

I installed `garamondx` as shown below. However, when I try to incorporate it into a document, I get the following error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ugmr8a.pfb): cannot open Type
 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Here is a minimal example of source code which produces the error:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

I can compile normal text just fine. However, when I use math mode, I get an error : 
\[x = y.\]

\end{document}
```

I compiled it with `pdflatexmk` so maybe that is the problem.

---

*Installation of* `garamondx` *using* `getnonfreefonts`

I was able to install `getnonfreefonts` and `garamondx` as follows

```
jack@Jacks-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
Password:
Detected System: x86_64-darwin
Detected Installation: /usr/local/texlive/2019
mkdir /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts ...     [done]
Installing texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.pl ...     [done]
Installing texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.1 ...                 [done]
Installing texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...          [done]
md5sum: a9e772165e8fdb620bcf9c75c17facda getnonfreefonts.pl ...            [ok]
md5sum: 49be4444054d85b6037d237552a7cea1 getnonfreefonts.1 ...             [ok]
md5sum: f825d523d686dbecdc787535b40f09d0 getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...      [ok]
Fixing File Permissions ...                                              [done]
Creating symlink in 'bin/x86_64-darwin' ...                              [done]
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.

jack@Jacks-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo getnonfreefonts --sys garamondx
Password:
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 34361  100 34361    0     0  47591      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 47591
------------------------------------------------------
 Installation directory: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
------------------------------------------------------

====================
Package 'garamondx':
====================

Downloading 'http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/garamondx.tds.zip'


 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   327  100   327    0     0   1302      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1297
100 2395k  100 2395k    0     0   841k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 1408k
                                                            [download done]

Checking integrity of file 'garamondx.tds.zip'...                          [ok]

d81a2e0bc611480e58e414bf9585cc86  garamondx.tds.zip                 [MD5sum ok]

Extracting 'garamondx.tds.zip'...                                        [done]
Installing 'zgm.map'...updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/jack) to root's actual home (/var/root).
Creating new config file /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
                                              [done]

Running 'mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local >/dev/null 2>/dev/null' ... [done]

Updating map files (updmap-sys). Be patient...updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/jack) to root's actual home (/var/root).
                       [done]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Type1 font file `ugmr8a.pfb`, which is used by `mathdesign` with the `urw-garamond` option, comes with the `garamond` package. This means you can fix this issue using:

```
sudo getnonfreefonts --sys garamond
```

I have both `garamond` and `garamondx` installed, and your sample code works without problems for me.

Concerning bold italic math: the `bm` package still works for me when loaded after the other font changing packages:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}    
\[ l \neq \bm{l} \]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What is the best way to use bold italic math characters with Garamond? For example in the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamondexpertmathdesign/), the Biot-Savart law is typeset using this font and it has a bold italic lowercase L. I used to do this with `\bm` but that doesn't work anymore. It changes the font to Computer Modern.

Comment: @simplejack Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was loading the `bm` package too early.